# the kubernetes pod container exists with Segmentation fault when running rust pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rust

Today I found the kubernetes pod shows log:

```
Back-off restarting failed container
```

the container shows exists info:

```
terminated
Reason: Error - exit code: 139
```

and the pod always did not ready and could not serve the request, but when I check the pod log:

```
 release git:(main) kubectl logs admin-service-5bdf47b85c-bdqdw -n reddwarf-pro
➜  release git:(main)
```

there is no message output. why did this happen? what should I do to fix this problem? This is the Dockerfile:

```
# to reduce the docker image size
# build stage
FROM rust:1.54-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN rustup default stable
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache libpq musl-dev pkgconfig openssl-dev postgresql-dev
RUN cargo build --release
# RUN cargo build

# Prod stage
FROM alpine:3.15
WORKDIR /app
ENV ROCKET_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
# ENV ROCKET_PORT=11014
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache libpq curl
COPY --from=builder /app/.env /app
COPY --from=builder /app/settings.toml /app
COPY --from=builder /app/target/release/reddwarf-admin /app/
COPY --from=builder /app/Rocket.toml /app
CMD ["./reddwarf-admin"]
```

could not login into docker container by any ways. when I using describe command:

```
➜  release git:(main) kubectl describe pod admin-service-745dc87489-j647l -n reddwarf-pro

Name:         admin-service-745dc87489-j647l
Namespace:    reddwarf-pro
Priority:     0
Node:         k8smasterone/172.29.217.209
Start Time:   Mon, 02 May 2022 14:19:10 +0800
Labels:       app=admin-service
              pod-template-hash=745dc87489
Annotations:  cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: 41763a38ee120ae7c85cd11fda699f30205a06fe9a5b6175736390d503c26bd3
              cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 10.97.196.208/32
              cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 10.97.196.208/32
Status:       Running
IP:           10.97.196.208
IPs:
  IP:           10.97.196.208
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/admin-service-745dc87489
Containers:
  admin-service:
    Container ID:   containerd://406e183d166b861448aa2d3597d3d190ccd5432e92b031721cae356ab00b59b2
    Image:          registry.cn-hongkong.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-pro/reddwarf-admin:f1e71525c1996a711f67ca85715d190bafcee07d
    Image ID:       registry.cn-hongkong.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-pro/reddwarf-admin@sha256:b39bebf332bc53318e29c8f697592bf76eb9e1676b74017d87c109a74ad3f235
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    139
      Started:      Mon, 02 May 2022 14:22:02 +0800
      Finished:     Mon, 02 May 2022 14:22:03 +0800
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  5
    Limits:
      cpu:     50m
      memory:  60Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:     20m
      memory:  6Mi
    Environment:
      DATABASE_URL:        <set to the key 'database_url' of config map 'admin-service-pro-config'>        Optional: false
      MUSIC_DATABASE_URL:  <set to the key 'music_database_url' of config map 'admin-service-pro-config'>  Optional: false
      QUARK_DATABASE_URL:  <set to the key 'quark_database_url' of config map 'admin-service-pro-config'>  Optional: false
      DICT_DATABASE_URL:   <set to the key 'dict_database_url' of config map 'admin-service-pro-config'>   Optional: false
      ENV:                 <set to the key 'env' of config map 'admin-service-pro-config'>                 Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-6gfdl (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-6gfdl:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  4m8s                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned reddwarf-pro/admin-service-745dc87489-j647l to k8smasterone
  Normal   Pulled     2m42s (x5 over 4m7s)   kubelet            Container image "registry.cn-hongkong.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-pro/reddwarf-admin:f1e71525c1996a711f67ca85715d190bafcee07d" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    2m42s (x5 over 4m7s)   kubelet            Created container admin-service
  Normal   Started    2m41s (x5 over 4m7s)   kubelet            Started container admin-service
  Warning  BackOff    2m16s (x10 over 4m5s)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

when I pull the image into local MacBook Pro, it works fine. By the way, the server running containerd not using docker.

Comment: Can you verify your `deployment` & `service` objects  are well configured, and also you can download `Lens` which It's an intuitive opensource tool  It gives you a nice interface for getting different infos about your `cluster` and `K8s ressources`, you can also access to your `pods` logs from that.

Comment: I finally found that the problem was caused by the rust main process, the rust process exists after run. The rust was encount `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error. I am confusing why did this happen. I am using rust + alpine + containerd. @Aladin

Comment: So you basically trying to access to unauthorized ressource (maybe something related to tls security, or firewall), or the `service` is using a limited memory (try to configure your service again with a limited memory & cpu ressource).


You can also check  [this](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/docker-alpine-3-segmentation-fault/64279/6)